# Vectorized implementation of kmeans++

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

I have implemented [the kmeans++ algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means%2B%2B) to initialize clusters when performing K-means clustering. The loop has to run `k` times. I was wondering if there was any way to vectorize the algorithm to get it to run faster?

`points` is an array of points in d-dimensions and `k` is the number of centroids to return.

It works by calculating the minimum distances from the already found clusters, to all the points and then calculating the probability of choosing the next cluster from the points.

The issue is really that it scales badly when `k` is large.

```py
def init_plus_plus(points, k):
    centroids = np.zeros_like(points[:k])
    r = np.random.randint(0, points.shape[0])
    centroids[0] = points[r]

    for i in range(1, k):

        min_distances = self.euclidian_distance(centroids[:i], points).min(1)
        prob = min_distances / min_distances.sum()
        cs = np.cumsum(prob)
        idx = np.sum(cs < np.random.rand())
        centroids[i] = points[int(idx)]

    return centroids
```

Comment: What is `self`?

Comment: @kwinkunks It's just the class that this belongs to where there is a function for calculating the distance between to sets of points, or in this case a number of centroids and the points

Comment: If you can, you should avoid this kind of thing -- better to write 'pure' functions and pass this `self` object in as an argument to this function. But that's just a detail... Have you tried profiling your code? Just asking because I've seen speedups from re-implementing scipy distance functions, which have bells & whistles, with plain `np.linalg.norm()`.